# Amazon Alexa Get Access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

I am writing a SmartHome skill and need an access token to post asyncrhonous notifications for a device (doorbell). The documentation is confusing - but from what I have infered - I am supposed to get my client_id and client_secret from the Alexa console, and get the Bearer Token during the initial skill connection/authorization, then request the access token (and refresh token) via OAuth. So I can get these three pieces of info, but then I try to do:

```
curl -vv X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' -d "\
grant_type=authorization_code\
&code=$CODE\
&client_id=$CLIENT_ID\
&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token
```

Where CODE came from the initial authorization request as:

```
        "payload": {
            "grant": {
                "code": "<<REDACTED>>",
                "type": "OAuth2.AuthorizationCode"
            },
```

But this always gives me:

`{"error_description":"The request has an invalid parameter : code","error":"invalid_grant"}`

If I *remove* the `code` parameter it complains it's missing, and if I *change* the code to something invalid, the error changes from `invalid_grant` to `invalid_request`. So it understands the code - but doesn't like something about this whole flow.

(I know the `client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_types` are valid, because when I change them to something deliberately erroneous, I get some expected error).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: While I was testing what I noticed was during some of my action my client id and secret got changed, and my test scripts stopped working. You can double check client id and secret, by going to developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask in action choose edit for skill required, then go to permissions and click on show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can only be used *once* - whether it succeeds or not. So even if you use it and your request is botched or otherwise doesn't work - you cannot reuse it. The only was I was able to handle this was to disable the skill, re-enabled it, then snoop and use the *new* code given.